# Include the hour in the filename for a log file

Tags: solaris, ksh

I have a ksh script where I'm creating a logFileName as follows:

```
logFileName=result_`date +%y%m%d_%k%M%S`.log
```

This results in a correct filename most of the time like the following:

```
result_121127_121010.log
```

However, at midnight it results in the following filename:

```
result_121127_ 01010.log
```

Thoughts on how to fix this?  Basically, I'm looking for something other than `%k` to find the hour with the date command in ksh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace %k by %H as the former isn't padding the hour with 0 for single digit hours.

```
logFileName=result_`date +%y%m%d_%H%M%S`.log
```

or the equivalent

```
logFileName=result_$(date +%y%m%d_%H%M%S).log
```

Note that the famous Y2K bug showed it is better to use a full year like:

```
logFileName=result_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).log
```

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason I couldn't find the H online, and I appreciate the Y suggestion as well.